# Do Scout achievements regarding 'stun' mechanics still work following changes to The Sandman?

Tags: achievements, team-fortress-2, tf2-scout

In TF2, a good bit of the Scout's achievements involve stunning enemies. With the change to the [Sandman](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Sandman), do these achievements still work?

An example of one of these achievements is "[Brushback](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Obtaining_Scout_achievements)," which has you stunning 50 enemies who are pushing the cart. Does stun just mean hitting them with a ball and applying a slow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes.**
Valve [says](http://www.teamfortress.com/jungleinferno/notes.php) they updated the achievements. This is from the Jungle Inferno patch notes.

> Long-range ball impacts no longer remove the victim's ability to fire their weapon (but the victim is still slowed)
> We've updated achievements that were looking for disarmed players.

People on [reddit](http://reddit.com/r/tf2/comments/8nz4y0/is_it_possible_to_get_moon_shot_achivement_after/) confirm it is still possible to get the [Moon Shot achievement](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Obtaining_Scout_achievements), which used to require a maximum duration stun. While the achievement description has not changed, the condition is now a maximum duration slow.

Any achievement which required a 'stun' should now instead require a 'slow' even though the text description has not changed.

Comment: Alright, thanks! I was worried the achievements would become completely broken, which would not surprise me.